# Java Generics - Type Mismatch Error

Tags: java, generics

I have a class defined as follows:

```
public class MultiFacilitySearchDataProvider <T extends Facility & MilepostValue & Copyable<T>>
```

The class has this method:

```
 protected T getFacility(final FacilityInstance instance) { 
   final MultiFacilitySearchDAO dao = new MultiFacilitySearchDAO(instance); 
   ENM.execute(dao); 
   return dao.getResultModel(); // Compile error here 
}
```

The DAO method called above looks like this:

```
 public MultiFacilitySearchModel getResultModel() { 
    return resultModel; 
 }
```

And MultiFacilitySearchModel is defined as follows:

```
public class MultiFacilitySearchModel implements Copyable<MultiFacilitySearchModel>, Facility, 
 Serializable, MilepostValue, MenuDisplayValues
```

The problem is that the line return dao.getResultModel() generates a compile error "**Type mismatch: cannot convert from MultiFacilitySearchModel to T**". I don't understand why I'm getting this error, since MultiFacilitySearchModel implements the three interfaces specified for the generic type T. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

You can specify any class that meets the prequesites as type parameter. Therefore `T` need not be a supertype of `MultiFacilitySearchModel`. That means however, that

```
return dao.getResultModel()
```

may not return an object of a type that extends `T`. Java doesn't allow you to do this.

Answer (score 1):

The method `MultiFacilitySearchDAO.getResultModel()` has no generic type and will allways return `MultiFacilitySearchModel` instead of `T`.

Although `MultiFacilitySearchModel` can be used as `T` in some class that extends `MultiFacilitySearchDataProvider`.

Answer (score 0):

In your class `MultiFacilitySearchDAO` you have the method

```
public MultiFacilitySearchModel getResultModel()
```

which is obviously returning an instance of `MultiFacilitySearchModel`. There is nothing generic here. The return type is fix.

Your class `MultiFacilitySearchDataProvider` on the other hand declares the method

```
protected T getFacility(final FacilityInstance instance)
```

The type variable `T` is constrained to implement the three interfaces `Facility & MilepostValue & Copyable`. This is much less then being a `MultiFacilitySearchModel`.

I could easily create a class

```
public MyFacilitySearchModel implements Copyable<MyFacilitySearchModel>, Facility, MilepostValue
```

and then use a

```
MultiFacilitySearchDataProvider<MyFacilitySearchModel>
```

The result type of `getResultModel()` would still be `MultiFacilitySearchModel` which can't be casted to `MyFacilitySearchModel`.

Maybe you DAO class should also be generic. Or declare the method as

```
protected MultiFacilitySearchModel getFacility(final FacilityInstance instance)
```